# Can ICANN really cancel your domains if you dont provide them with your personal data?

Tags: domain-registrar, icann

Hi,

my registrar is requiring me to update my contact information and they say that if its not accurate (in other words if I am LYING) ICANN can cancel my domain. I really dont mind giving away my email address, but my PHYSICAL address is a different thing. Thats PRIVATE and sensitive information and I dont want that to be public. I am paying my registrar to conceal this data from whois pages but still, I would rather not give it away so in the past I always submitted made up data. Can ICANN ever know its not really your address?

Thank you.

Comment: From the icann website "It's important to keep your contact information up-to-date", they don't say "it is required".   https://www.icann.org/en/blogs/details/do-you-have-a-domain-name-heres-what-you-need-to-know-part-1-31-8-2017-en

Comment: ICANN won't cancel the domain but if somebody disputes your ownership of the domain and ICANN can't contact you, they will proceed with a judgement and you won't get a say in the proceedings.  In other words, you need to have valid contact info to protect your domain from being taken in a dispute.

Comment: well, I provide an email address which is real so they can contact me.